# νz (z3opt): Unable to make an Optimize object using Java API

Tags: z3

I'm trying to use Max-SMT using the Java API. Below is my attempt:

```
Optimize opt = ctx.mkOptimize();
opt.Add(hardConstraints);
for(BoolExpr c : C){
  opt.AssertSoft(c, 1, "group");
}
```

However, there is a runtime error in the first line, where `opt` is created.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.microsoft.z3.Native.INTERNALmkOptimize(J)J    at
>   com.microsoft.z3.Native.INTERNALmkOptimize(Native Method)     at
>   com.microsoft.z3.Native.mkOptimize(Native.java:5237)  at
>   com.microsoft.z3.Optimize.(Optimize.java:265)   at
>   com.microsoft.z3.Context.mkOptimize(Context.java:3036)

I'm using the latest version of Z3 from Github, downloaded on Sept 30th.

Comment: Did you compile Z3 from sources or did you use a binary download?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I compiled Z3 from sources. I'm using Mac OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX, make sure that the System Integrity Protection doesn't interfere with your work. In this setting it may remove the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment setting from your environment when it starts the JVM, which has the effect that `*.dylib` can't be found.

For Z3-specific information see [Z3 Java API fails to detect libz3.dylib](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/294). For general info about SIP see [About System Integrity Protection on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899). I haven't found a good way to tell OSX that Z3 is "safe" yet without disabling SIP altogether.